# Use of String Constant

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

I have references to **ground** and **air** in multiple files. It is usually used in this context, but not always.

```
if ([transport.type isEqualToString:@"ground"]) {
  // do something for automobiles
}
else if ([transport.type isEqualToString:@"air"]) {
  // do something else for planes
}
else {
  // we don't care
}
```

Should I be using string constants to represent **ground** and **air** so if I ever change their literal, I just update it in one place? e.g.

```
NSString * const TransportGround = @"ground";
NSString * const TransportAir = @"air";
```

I then decide I want to rename **ground** to be **wheels**, then I would only update the above string constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like it would be a good idea to define constants like you proposed, most likely in the `Transport` class.

While consolidating it into a single location makes long term management easier, it can also help prevent errors that would arise if you happened to misspell one of those separate `@"ground"` or `@"air"` instances.

For example, if in one of the classes where you check the transport type and you accidently misspell `@"air"` as `@"iar"`, the code would not act as you expect, nor would you have any warning or error generated. By using defined constants, you have the help of the compiler to make sure you spell the defined constants correctly. For example, there's no way you could spell `TransportAir` as `TransportIar`, as the compiler would issue an error when you tried to compile.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `String` in a lot of places then it would be beneficial to create a constant and refer back to that, mainly for if you change it like you mentioned, rather than hard coding every instance. If you only use the string in a couple of places it might not be necessary. Really it's a style decision.

Answer (score 1):

From a code-maintenance point of view, this might be a good idea - particularly if you're likely to change those literals later on. This is additionally particularly useful if those strings are for showing to users and you think you might want to translate your program into multiple languages in future.

In the event that you're only going to use those literals once, or don't intend on changing them, then it's probably not so good an idea, as putting code in lots of different places makes the code more difficult to read than if the string constant is directly inlined.

If you're asking does it make any difference to the end-program, the answer is no. In both cases the literal gets put in the string-pool and the program will load it from there whether it's an inline string constant or defined as a string constant elsewhere.